cannot upgrade from "lunar" to "noble"
Trying upgrade with "do-release-upgrade" and got the message
"Can not upgrade
An upgrade from 'lunar' to 'noble' is not supported with this tool."
The same result with "software & updates"
No disk shortage, ram - 32g
Any ideas?

The supported upgrade path from 23.04 was to the next release, or Ubuntu 23.10 (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ManticUpgrades)  with upgrades available for 24.04 (noble) from either mantic (23.10) or 22.04 (jammy) or the prior LTS (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NobleUpgrades)   The upgrade tool does NOT support your path; 22.10, 23.04, 23.10 & 24.04 are the same cycle; and once on that two-year-development cycle the supported upgrade path is thru all releases. (22.04 or the final last-cycle release could jump into the 22.10-24.04 cycle at any point, but only that first jump)
